# Analytic geometry using Python OOP

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, object, geometry

So I've just delved into OOP programming for the first time. I came across an exercise where we're supposed to write a script using OOP that creates a rectangle, calculates it's area and circumference, and the area of overlapping with a second rectangle. So far, so good, I managed to work it out. However, once I had solved it, I checked the given solution, and it looks something like this:

```
from copy import copy

class Point:

    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return '({}, {})'.format(self.x, self.y)


class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, point, width, height):
        self.point = copy(point)
        self.width = abs(width)
        self.height = abs(height)
        if self.width == 0:
            self.width == 1
        if self.height == 0:
            self.height == 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return '[{}, w = {}, h = {}]'.format(self.point, self.width, self.height)

    def surface_area(self):
        return self.width * self.height

    def circunference(self):
        return 2*(self.width + self.height)

    def bottom_right(self):
        return Point(self.point.x + self.width, self.point.y + self.height)

    def overlap(self, r):
        r1, r2 = self, r
        if self.point.x > r.point.x or (self.point.x == r.point.x and self.point.y > r.point.y):
            r1, r2 = r, self
        if r1.bottom_right().x <= r2.point.x or r1.bottom_right().y <= r2.point.y:
            return None
        return Rectangle(r2.point,
            min(r1.bottom_right().x - r2.point.x, r2.width),
            min(r1.bottom_right().y - r2.point.y, r2.height))


r1 = Rectangle(Point(1, 1), 8, 5)
r2 = Rectangle(Point(2, 3), 9, 2)

print(r1, '\n', r1.surface_area(), '\n', r1.circunference(), '\n', r1.bottom_right())
r = r1.overlap(r2)
if r:
    print(r)
else:
    print('No, overlap.')
```

My problem is with the *bottom_right* method. I'm quite sure that it returns the top right, not the bottom right. But since I still struggle to fully grasp this logic in continuity, I fear I might be the one who's in fault. If indeed the solution is correct (the method returns the bottom right vertex), then there's something I'm missing and thus I can't fully comprehend this code.

Answer (score 1):

This is just because usually in computer graphics, the origin is set at the top left corner.  So, you would actually have a flipped y-axis as compared to what you are used to in geometry in math.

So instead, you have something like this:
[image]

Therefore, the point `(X, Y)` is actually at the bottom right of the rectangle starting at point `(0, 0)` and having width `X` and height `Y`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of implicit assumptions in your program...

If you are defining your `Rectangle` with a `Point` at the top-left corner, a `width` and a `height` in pixels, ***and*** if you are using a cartesian coordinate system where the `x` axis points left, and the `y` axis up, your `bottom_right` method returns the top right coordinates.

You can change it to:

```
def bottom_right(self):
    return Point(self.point.x + self.width, self.point.y - self.height)
```